# How to handle this obscure error when doing a join in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am running a join on a spark databricks cluster. The join is between two entities, one of them is bucketed. Both dataframe have the same number of partitions and are partitioned/bucketed by the join key.

I am getting the following error when running it:

> There should be only one distinct value of the number pre-shuffle
>   partitions among registered Exchange operator

I'd appreciate any help for dealing with it.

Comment: Why the vote to close?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens when you have different number of pre-shuffle partitions (i.e. map output partitions) in the bucket. For eg if you have 10 partitions in one bucket and 20 in other this is supposed to happen.

Spark ensures it doesn't get the different  number of pre-shuffle partitions for stages.

From the comment in Spark code:

> The reason that we are expecting a single value of the number of pre-shuffle partitions
>   is that when we add Exchanges, we set the number of pre-shuffle partitions
>    (i.e. map output partitions) using a static setting, which is the value of
>   spark.sql.shuffle.partitions. Even if two input RDDs are having different number of partitions, they will have the same number of pre-shuffle partitions

So you need to ensure both the bucketed dataframe has same number of partitions inside each bucket.

Comment: Avishek, thanks for the answer but I am not sure I understand: I already made sure both dataframes have the same number of partitions. To be more exact: one of the data frames has 100 buckets and the other has 100 parittions (with repartition). I basically followed the example [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-bucketing.html), the one talking about bucketing only one side of the join. Can you elaborate more about what I need to do and why?

Comment: Actually, I found out that one of the buckets in the read path was written by a different flow, so what you are saying totally makes sense. I made sure the flows are the same and the issue was resolved.